# whats wrong with my update query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

i am having an issue with a MySQL update query, it says successful but doesn't actually update the database record.

```
require_once('auth.php');

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="sysadmin"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="Elite"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Triage"; // Table name 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$Reference=$_GET['Reference'];

$sql="UPDATE Triage SET directly='$directly' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: Ask your question from `mysql_error()` - it has exact answer

Comment: Use of MySQL rather than mysqli or pdo; no validation of user inputs, no error handling; $directly isn't defined anywhere.... that's the first few items on the list of what's wrong

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Change that line to this, to the one above and you'll get your answer

Comment: $directly isn't defined..... so you didnt update anything

Comment: @Simon_eQ and Alma, why will mysql_error() help? The query is successful as far as mysql_query is concerned, there is no error and so mysql_error() will return an empty string.

Comment: they are all defined on a previous page on a form, do they also need to be on this page?

Comment: @Luke see my updated answer - variables don't automatically persist to other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define `$directly` and so the `directly` field will be updated with an empty string. Keep in mind that `mysql_query()` will still return `true` if the field wasn't changed (ie it was already an empty string) and no error occurred.

If `$directly` was defined on a previous page, it won't automatically persist to another page. You will have to either persist it in the `$_SESSION` or some other medium, or pass it as a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable.

---

Side note: `mysql_*` is deprecated and your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Consider upgrading to PDO or MySQLi with a Prepared Statement and bound parameters.

Comment: Its not good to encourage people, by answering their crappy questions, of which is answered in the comment section.

Comment: @MrCode thanks for this, i will give it a try now, i think i know what i need to do now, Cheers

Comment: If you want to delete the session data you can use `session_destroy()`.

Comment: cheers, and this was part of the code on the previous page.
    <tr>
    <td><div align="center">9</div></td>
    <td><strong>Was the client spoken to directly? </strong></td>
    <td align="center"><div align="left">
    <input name="directly" type="text" id="directly" value="<? echo $rows['directly']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="50" reference="directly" />
    </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

Comment: Yes, it looks like you have it in a form variable, so you can use `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Is this solved now?

Comment: could you please tell me where i would use  $_GET or $_POST and yes you solved my issue, just need to implement it now. =D

Comment: If your form has a method of `post` and it posts to this page, then you can get the variable with `$_POST['directly']`. If the form's method is `get` then use `$_GET['directly']`. This will only work if the form is submitting to this page.....

Answer (score 1):

While writing any query, you should first check whether variables are defined or not like this :

```
if(isset($directly) && isset($Reference)){
  $sql="UPDATE Triage SET directly='$directly' WHERE Reference='$Reference'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

And mysql_* extension is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) as of php5.5.0, Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.